# Slowdown when reading big file randomly with C++

Tags: c++, file, memory, io

I've run into some trouble when reading chunks of data at random locations all over a big file (>4GB).
The task is to save a 3D datacube to a file and transpose the axes while not loading the whole dataset into RAM.
The storage format is as follows:
I've got 3 Integer at the beginning of the File, storing the dimensions (nX, nY, nZ ).
After that follows the data as lines with length nX.
These Lines are repeated nY times which results in a page and the pages are repeated nZ times.
Meaning:
A line has nX bytes
A page has nX * nY bytes
The file has nX * nY * nZ + 12 bytes
To transpose the dataset i execute the following loop:

```
for( int i=0;i<nY;i++ )
{
    for( int j=0;j<nZ;j++ )
    {
        read( pBuf, i*nX+j*nY*nX );//read nX bytes from offset i*nX+j*nX*nY
        writeNext(pBuf);
    }
}
```

When using fopen, _fseeki64 and fread it happens that after approx. 30% of the overall reads every 6th read or so takes up to 7 s, since there are multiple millions of those reads i can't accept these delays.
Thus i implemented the same algorithm with memory mapped files (CreateFile, CreateFileMapping and MapViewOfFile), but now every 6th read takes about 2 s.
Is there a method/chance of increasing the readout speed?


EDIT1:
I've added some code at http://pastebin.com/MejiTKj0
EDIT2:
Some may notice an inconsistency regarding the offset in the read function. To simplify matters i didn't tell about all variables saved in the file header thus the offset of 15 bytes is okay

Comment: Just to be sure, you are using NTFS, are you? Not some crazy filesystem such as exFAT...

Comment: Something is definitely wrong. Though seeks are slow, they shouldn't be measured in seconds. Can you please show more of your code?

Comment: @rodrigo I use NTFS

Comment: @Leon http://pastebin.com/MejiTKj0

Comment: @Krustenkaese Thanks. What about the write function? We may go through less cycles if you share all your code.

Comment: @Leon The write function is only a dummy for TIFFWriteScanline, which is part of the libtiff library and isn't the bottleneck. I've isolated the given read function as the most time consuming procedure.
TIFFWriteScanline takes about 150 ms max.

Comment: I would expect to offset by the 3 integer as well in the read (12 bytes)

Comment: Is the file located on a local disk?

Comment: @Alessandro Teruzzi The Offset is fine because to simplify things i didn't tell about some more variables i'm saving so 15 is okay... if you look into the routine opening the file you'll se the missing bytes :D

Comment: Is the posted code enough to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Karoly Horvath To repoduce my problem i would have to send you a 4GB file containing my measurements... everything else is written like i've posted... although i'm down from 4hrs computation time to 15 min... I'm slowly getting used to it :D

Comment: What are the values of m_nElemSize, m_nXDim, m_nXDim and m_nYDim?

Comment: @Krustenkaese: have you actually *tested* the minimal code you've posted?

Comment: "Every 6th read" - is it a strict statement, or just something giving an idea?

Comment: @Leon m_nElemSize = 2, m_nXDim = 2550, m_nYDim = 820, m_nZDim = 978 and when using File Mapping it is strict and when using fread it isn't as strict :D

Comment: Have you verified that this is not a problem caused by a bad hard drive? ("Every 6th read" is an extremely specific fault to be consistent.) Does the HDD demonstrate these qualities when you are running other applications or is it just an issue with this one application? Finally, have you verified that there are no other bugs that could be causing a slowdown (such as a processing loop) and it is actually the seek itself that is slow?

Comment: @Chris Britt I actually didn't think about checking the hard drive... Thanks a lot, will do that next thing tomorrow. softwarebugs aren't likely because i've reduced the code to a minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all very much for your input.
Actually the first thing i should have checked was at fault, being the HDD, which wasn't able to provide the needed datarate.
I'm now thinking about switching to a SSD - Device.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a HDD disk on which the files are stored, you should know that seek times dominate heavily when trying to perform random access. You may find you're better off reading the entire file sequentially into memory (a relatively quick operation compared to seek) and then performing your processing on the memory data instead. You may find this is quicker even if you need only a relatively small percentage of the overall file data.

Comment: Anyway, seek time of a HDD should never be 6 seconds long! There has to be a better explanation...

Answer (score 0):

In your loop Z / nZ should be outer most loop and Y should be inner loop. That would save seek times, if the storage memory layout has stored a nZ pages one by one .

In the current code displayed it shows nZ in inner loop, which is no good. The current arrangement of loops is analogous to book reading, with reading first line for each page of the book, then reading second line and so on;

Comment: That's done on purpose, so that writes are consecutive.